# git is adding control characters to my command string and thus blows up '$'\033''[m'

Tags: git

I am trying to run a git bash command that used to work, but recently fails.  I have no idea what changed between then and now (no new git d/l).

Here's the command reference:
git status | grep 'deleted:' | cut -d':' -f2  | xargs -t   -I {}  git add  -u "{}"

Now I want to hijack the tail end of this so I can feed multiple files into git commands.
git status
..
Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
Docs/collisions_bbox_08232021.jpg
Docs/collisions_bbox_08232021.psd
Fml/collisions_082321.flt
Fml/scaleRef/sgn_one_way_Low_2f_scale.flt
Fml/scaleRef/sgn_wrong_way_do_not_enter_Low_3f_scale.flt
..

My command:
$ git status | grep Fml
Fml/collisions_082321.flt
Fml/scaleRef/sgn_one_way_Low_2f_scale.flt
Fml/scaleRef/sgn_wrong_way_do_not_enter_Low_3f_scale.flt

Here's the problem:

```
xxx MINGW64 /e/sss/ProjectData (master)
$ git status | grep Fml | xargs -t -I {} git add -u "{}"
git add -u ''$'\033''[31mFml/collisions_082321.flt'$'\033''[m'
fatal: pathspec '?[31mFml/collisions_082321.flt?[m' did not match any files
git add -u ''$'\033''[31mFml/scaleRef/sgn_one_way_Low_2f_scale.flt'$'\033''[m'
fatal: pathspec '?[31mFml/scaleRef/sgn_one_way_Low_2f_scale.flt?[m' did not match any files
git add -u ''$'\033''[31mFml/scaleRef/sgn_wrong_way_do_not_enter_Low_3f_scale.flt'$'\033''[m'
fatal: pathspec '?[31mFml/scaleRef/sgn_wrong_way_do_not_enter_Low_3f_scale.flt?[m' did not match any files
```

Google isn't helping, maybe b/c it's processing the special characters.  Any idea what is going on that the git (command processor?) is mangling my input?  How do I reformat the command string so it works?

Thanks for checking.

Comment: Those ESC [ <digits-etc> m sequences are how Git convinces your terminal window to switch *colors* (and other such effects). This suggests you've set `color.ui` to `always` rather than `auto`: normally Git tries to guess whether the output from some user-facing command (like `git status`) is actually going to a user, and if so, switch on fancy color mode; if not, the command will print only the raw text. That's what `auto` means, in color settings: "make a guess". This ... mostly works. :-)

Comment: To make things work always, we have to write our own programs using the Git tools that Git calls *plumbing* commands (or add `--porcelain` in some rare-ish cases, with `git status` being one of those) to tell the tool: *this output is meant for another program to use, so make it easy for a computer to read, instead of easy for a human*.

Comment: Note that modern Git has `git status --porcelain=v2` as well now, which produces more data and is better-designed (the old `--porcelain` just did `--short` with color turned off).

Comment: thanks for the info!  Yes, I got tired of piped output being uncolored.

Answer (score 5):

You should not parse the output of `git status` use `git status --porcelain` instead, something like this lists the deleted files:

```
git status --porcelain | sed -n 's/^.D.//p'
```

For untrached files you would use:

```
git status --porcelain | sed -n 's/^??.//p'
```

Comment: Hm.  OK I'll give that a shot, but the reference string works, if I am deleting stuff.  Or it used to!  Note that I am trying to add files.

Comment: $ git status --porcelain | grep Fml | xargs -t   -I {}  git add  -u "{}"
git add -u '?? Fml/collisions_082321.flt'
fatal: pathspec '?? Fml/collisions_082321.flt' did not match any files
git add -u '?? Fml/scaleRef/sgn_one_way_Low_2f_scale.flt'
fatal: pathspec '?? Fml/scaleRef/sgn_one_way_Low_2f_scale.flt' did not match any files
git add -u '?? Fml/scaleRef/sgn_wrong_way_do_not_enter_Low_3f_scale.flt'
fatal: pathspec '?? Fml/scaleRef/sgn_wrong_way_do_not_enter_Low_3f_scale.flt' did not match any files

Comment: Just change the sed regex, for untracked files it would be: `s/^??.//p`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, silly me.

There are leading ?? in the return string from git, which are feeding into the command string:

```
MINGW64 /e/ssss/ProjectData (master)
$ git status --porcelain | grep Fml
?? Fml/collisions_082321.flt
?? Fml/scaleRef/sgn_one_way_Low_2f_scale.flt
?? Fml/scaleRef/sgn_wrong_way_do_not_enter_Low_3f_scale.flt
```

When I process these out, the command input works again:

```
$ git status --porcelain | grep Fml | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs -t   -I {}  git add  -u "{}"
git add -u Fml/collisions_082321.flt
git add -u Fml/scaleRef/sgn_one_way_Low_2f_scale.flt
git add -u Fml/scaleRef/sgn_wrong_way_do_not_enter_Low_3f_scale.flt
```

Thanks to andlrc for the --porcelain tip!